# PHP How To Show Hide DIVS based on Query String Value

Tags: php, pageload

Essentially, I'm completely new at PHP - using dreamweaver cs6 (its all i have)

I have to get the value of a query string (someurl.com/id=something).
After i get the value, I need to show a single div based on the ID.

While I know there really isn't any REAL "page load" event for PHP, I'd like to have it when the page opens.

So, how do I accomplish this?

I started with this:

```
<?php
    $stringId = $_GET['id']
   ?>

    <script language="javascript">      
        document.getElementById('$stringId').style.display = "block";
    </script>
    <?
?>
```

Since I don't have a server setup, will something like this work?
Would you suggest something else?
Am I completely wrong?

Any input would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Check out WAMP, XAMP etc. and get a testing environment going. You'll need one...

Comment: try  to use jquery  slideToggle()

Comment: 1) I'm doing this at work, I'd have to have IT do it for me, but I will try. (thanks)
2) jquery slideToggle() - I will check that out. (thanks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the style inline with out relying on javascript as some users may have javascript turned off.

```
<div <?php if($_GET['id'] == 'X'){ ?>style="display: block;"<?php } ?>>
    your div content
</div>
```

with an else as requested

```
<div style="<?php if($_GET['id'] == 'X'){ ?>display: block;<?php } else { ?>display: none;<?php } ?">
    your div content
</div>
```

you could also use a predefined css class

based on your comment about having way to many to do a switch if you need to mix it up just insert this

```
<script language="javascript">      
    document.getElementById('<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>').style.display = "block";
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be something like this:

```
<?php
switch($_GET['id']) {
    case 'asdf':
        echo '<div>ASDF in QS</div>';
        break;
    case 'bcd':
        echo '<div class="some-class-because-i-can">something else</div>';
}
```

You can't simply mix javascript with php.

And of course, you need servers setup, server built in php(http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) should be enough for your needs.

Comment: There are way too many to do that with, but that's a cool idea.

Comment: I might have to use that for something else I'm thinking of... so, thank you for that tidbit. :-)

Answer (score 1):

PHP is server-side scripting language, meaning it only runs on the server (any output being rendered on the users screen), that being said you need a local server like WAMP XAMP to debug/ run your code.

What you are trying to do is not going to work PHP is executed on the server as i previously mentioned and Javascript runs in the viewers browser, the variable $stringID will not be present when your javascript code runs.

Why bother hiding an element that has the url ID when PHP can render that element and only that element.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['id'])) {   //checks weather the link has data in the id field
       $stringId = $_GET['id'];

       echo "<div> content here </div>"; //anything you echo will be rendered in the 
                                         //pages source code be it HTML, Javascript etc.
    }
>?
```

If you want to fetch this data from php without refreshing the page use AJAX from jQuery (google it :D)

Comment: You pose a good point. But each of my divs has up to 15 lines of information in them, and I have about 20 or so divs.  That would take forever, lol. That's kind of why I was thinking of doing it this way.  but hey, that gives me another idea for another page i have - so thank you! :-)